# JOIN different methods with different query parameters : REST

Tags: java, api, get

Any alternative to this, because I think I cannot Overload REST requests.
But also I want to do a search by year, or by anything else. 
I have read that I should use a RequestMapping or something like that, but I don't use spring. I wnat to pass a query string (with all the filters) to the method. Any idea on how I could have just a only method do that?

```
@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getMovieByName(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @QueryParam("text") String name) {
    if (!checkLoggedIn(req)) {
        throw new WebApplicationException("User not logged.");
    }
    return buildResponse(movieService.getMovieByName(name));
}


@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getNumberOfMovies(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @QueryParam("n_movies") Integer total) {

    if (!checkLoggedIn(req)) {
    throw new WebApplicationException("User not logged.");
}
    return buildResponse(movieService.getNumberOfMovies(total));
}
```

Comment: Is it not enough fo to use multiple QueryParams in one method?

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider to use Map<> something like below :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-with-params",
                method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String sampleQueryParam(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
    return "You've hit the '/sample/get-with-params' request handler with the following query params:\n" + params;
}
```

More information is here : http://reypader.github.io/2015/12/21/spring-request-mapping.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html5/#introduction